# Position ImageViews with an offset programmatically

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have to create a stack of images programmatically (because they have to be dynamic).

I want to stack `ImageView`s like this:
[image: stack of images]

I've tried this, but the images all land up on top of each other:

```
for(int i=0; i<limit; i++){  

            dynamicButtons[i] = new ImageView(contextSosFragment);

            int offsetLeft = 15 * i;
            int offsetTop = 15 * i;
            layoutParamsDynamicButton.setMargins(offsetLeft, offsetTop, 0, 0);

            dynamicButtons[i].setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            dynamicButtons[i].setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            dynamicButtons[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.img_badge_dynamic_loading);
            dynamicButtons[i].setTag(id);

            containerDynamicButtons.addView(dynamicButtons[i], layoutParamsDynamicButton);
}
```

I've even removed the `android:gravity="center"` from my xml layout file.

I've also tried to add the layout params on the `ImageView` after setting the margins (`dynamicButtons[i].setLayoutParams(layoutParamsDynamicButton);`), but I read that that this might not take effect, because the layout params are for the parent and not the child of the container to which I add the `ImageView`s, that's why I tried to use `addView(view, layoutParams)`.

How can I position the `ImageView`s like this, programmatically?

### **SOLUTION:**

The solution was that I had to create a new layout params instance for each image - just like [Devunwired](https://stackoverflow.com/users/246461/devunwired) suggested. However, I also found that I had to change the `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` to be `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`. Only then did the change take effect.

The final for loop looks like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<limit; i++){
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsDynamicButton = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
            layoutParamsDynamicButton.bottomMargin = (int) getActivity().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.margin_badges);
            int offsetLeft = AppConstants.dynamic_button_offset_multiplier * i;
            int offsetTop = AppConstants.dynamic_button_offset_multiplier * i;
            layoutParamsDynamicButton.setMargins(offsetLeft, offsetTop, 0, 0);
            Log.d(TAG, "offset = "+offsetLeft);

            dynamicButtons[i] = new ImageView(contextSosFragment);
            dynamicButtons[i].setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            dynamicButtons[i].setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            dynamicButtons[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.img_badge_dynamic_loading);
            dynamicButtons[i].setTag(id);

            containerDynamicButtons.addView(dynamicButtons[i], layoutParamsDynamicButton);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each view needs its own `LayoutParams` object. It looks like your code just updates the same `LayoutParams` instance each time and passes it to `addView()`. If this is the case, all your views are pointing to the same params when it comes time to do layout...and their margins will all be the last value set.

As a performance optimization, if you are just placing several static images on top of each other, you could achieve the same effect (including the offsets) with a `LayerDrawable` ([docs link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html)) inside a single `ImageView`. This is the object created by `<layer-list>` in XML, but since you need to dynamically set the offset you could create one in code as well. Fewer views typically leads to cleaner UI.

Comment: This was the solution! I've had to learn the same principle when I created other buttons dynamically... I had to also change my layout parmas from LinearLayout.LayoutParms to be RelativeLayout.Layout params - only then did your solution take effect. Thank you!